# How can I have my mac display a reminder when it connects to a particular network?

Tags: network, notifications, reminders

I'd like my mac to display a reminder with a customized message every time it connects to a certain network.

The network can be distinguished by whether my mac's local IP address falls into a few possible IP address ranges, or whether the connection's gateway is one of three possible IP addresses. The connection could be Wi-Fi or ethernet.

Preferably the reminder would be an alert style notification that has to be manually dismissed, but I'm not wedded to that.

And just so that I don't get inundated with these notifications every time the network connects or disconnects for some random reason, I'd like to set it up so that I only get one of these reminders per day.

Is there a way I can set this up, short of writing my own piece of software?

edit: This question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146167/mavericks-i-need-to-be-notified-when-a-wifi-network-becomes-available) as I'm looking to see a customized reminder upon connecting to a specific local area network as determined by IP address, regardless of the network adapter used. That question is about being notified when a Wi-Fi network becomes available.

Comment: You're going to have to write some software (a script at least), so the answer to your question is, "No". Do you want ideas on how to go about that?

Comment: @Seamus No need, I'm a mac software developer so I know how to build this myself. I was just hoping there was an existing tool, feature or shortcut that would make it easier.

Comment: @NimeshNeema, et al: Duplicate? Perhaps, if you consider answers that are 5 years old which reference 3rd party solutions that are no longer maintained/viable. Is that truly a "duplicate"?